# Getting to next page via correct user input in Django

Tags: python, html, django

I wanted to create some "riddle" page but I got stuck in creating the functionality of the riddle itself.

So what I want to do is, I want to have just a plain HTML page where I can put some text/pictures, etc. and at the end of that block, there should be a user input prompt with a commit/send button.

If the input is the correct answer to the riddle, the user should get to the next riddle stage.
If not, he/she should get the info that the answer wasn't correct.

As I am learning Django right now I wondered how it should be designed according to it, and therefore I
have no sample code or anything.

I would really appreciate some help on how to do that because from what I understand I would need a function that takes the user input, compares it to some kind of a "solution database" and, depending on input, shows the user the specific page.

I already found some more sophisticated site protections to mimic this :
https://github.com/MaxLaumeister/pagecrypt/tree/master/python
but for my causes, I think it's a bit over the top.

Perhaps this topic is interesting for some of you,

Thank you!

Comment: The link you provided doesn't really relate to what you are asking. pagecrypt is a command line tool for encrypting (specifically) html pages. Doesn't seem relevant if you're building a django web app.

Comment: My best advice is to begin making! Often beginners spend too much time ruminating how to do something and end up not doing anything. Look at a few tutorials on Django (Django's documentation itself has a good tutorial, also its about making a polling app so might give you ideas), and then begin making your app.

Comment: Yes I know, i just wanted to show in a more visual way what I mean, with a simple prompt for the user to enter a password at the bottom of a page to get to the next one